# Populate textarea with chosen option

Tags: jquery, html

I have a chat system and I want to implement quick answers where the user can quickly answer "I'll deliver in 5 minutes", "I'll deliver in 10 minutes" or custom quick answer: "I'll deliver in" + numeric input field value + "minutes" (issue is in the last one).

Workflow:
1 - User selects one of the quick answers 
2 - The textarea of the chat system is then populated with the value from the previous chosen option

So far I am able to populate the textarea with the checkbox values.

However, I also need the value from the custom numeric input field.

```js
jQuery
// Only allow one option to be selected
jQuery('#send-information input').on('click', function() {
  jQuery('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    jQuery('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
});

// Gets and sets the value to populate the text area
jQuery('#send-information input').on('change', function() {
  // Checkbox values
  var chosenOption = jQuery('input[name=comment_text]:checked', '#send-information').val();
  // Numeric input value
  var typedOption = 'I will deliver in' + jQuery('#chat-test').val() + ' minutes';
  //Conditinal 
  if (chosenOption) {
    jQuery('.wooconvo-textarea').val(chosenOption);
    if (typedOption)
      jQuery('.wooconvo-textarea').val(typedOption);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" name="add_comment" id="send-information">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="comment_text" value="I'll deliver in 5 minutes"> I'll deliver in 5 minutes <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="comment_text" value="I'll deliver in 10 minutes">I'll deliver in 5 minutes<br>
    <input id="chat-test" type="number" name="comment_text2" /><br>
</form>

<form>
  <input type="textarea" class="wooconvo-textarea" />
</form>
```

I expect the textarea to populated with the checkbox value if some option is select and if not populate it with the custom time value set by the user.

Comment: FYI there's no `textarea` type of `input` in html. You may be looking for the `textarea` element, whose value you should set with `.text()`, not `.val()`

Comment: why not use `textarea` tag?

Comment: Yes, you're right! Thanks for pointing out that detail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed a bit in these lines, look at the demo and see if this is what you want;

```
if (chosenOption != undefined) {
  jQuery('.wooconvo-textarea').val(chosenOption);
} else if (typedOption) {
  jQuery('.wooconvo-textarea').val(typedOption);
}
```

The problem was that with your logic, every time we entered `if(chosenOption)` we would also go into `if (typedOption)`

**Demo**

```js
jQuery('#send-information input').on('click', function() {
  jQuery('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    jQuery('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
});

jQuery('#send-information input').on('change', function() {
  var chosenOption = jQuery('input[name=comment_text]:checked', '#send-information').val();
  var typedOption = 'I\'ll deliver in ' + jQuery('#chat-test').val() + ' minutes ';
  if (chosenOption != undefined) {
    jQuery('.wooconvo-textarea').val(chosenOption);
  } else if (typedOption) {
    jQuery('.wooconvo-textarea').val(typedOption);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" name="add_comment" id="send-information">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="comment_text" value="I'll deliver in 5 minutes"> I'll deliver in 5 minutes <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="comment_text" value="I'll deliver in 10 minutes">I'll deliver in 10 minutes<br>
    <input id="chat-test" type="number" name="comment_text2" /><br>
</form>
Textarea to populate:

<form>
  <input type="textarea" class="wooconvo-textarea" />
</form>
```